# Storybook fails to compile after upgrading Next.js to v6.0.3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, storybook

After upgrading Next.js to v6.0.3 my previously working setup stopped working.

**Storybook versions**

```
> "@storybook/addon-actions": "^3.4.2",
> "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "^3.4.2",
> "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^3.4.2",
> "@storybook/react": "^3.4.2",
```

**.stoyboojk/config.js**

```js
import { configure, addDecorator } from "@storybook/react";
import { configureViewport } from "@storybook/addon-viewport";
import { Provider } from "./Provider";
import "./main.css";

addDecorator(story => (
  <div dir="rtl" className="m-2 m-md-3">
    {story()}
  </div>
));
addDecorator(story => <Provider story={story()} />);

function loadStories() {
  //stories...
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading babel-core to v7.0.0 solved the problem for me:

```
npm install --save babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0
```